# C - function returns an array

Tags: c, arrays, methods

I'm writing a method that receives a number l and returns a vector of size l with random numbers. I have this code, but does not work

```
#include <time.h>    

 int makea (int z) {
    int a1[z];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < tam; i++) {
        a1[i]=srand(time(0));
    }
    return a1;
 }
```

These are the errors that the compiler returns me

> arrays1.c: In function 'makea':
>   arrays1.c:12: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be 
>   arrays1.c:14: warning: return makes integer from pointer without a cast
>   arrays1.c:14: warning: function returns address of local variable

I think is a problem of pointers... but I'm not really sure

Comment: You _can't_ return arrays from functions in C, you need to return a pointer to an array. Try using malloc to create your array.

Comment: first of all, this is very basic question and answer is in any C book (K&R, c-faq). 2) when you provide error output, make sure you mark lines (12,14) in code (copy and paste from IDE or do it manually).

Comment: Btw, C does not use "methods", it uses functions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A few problems:

1. Your array is allocated on the stack, meaning that when your function exits, the memory you return will be invalid
2. In C, you cannot return an array from a function, it must first decay into a pointer.

So, to fix, use malloc and a pointer:

```
int *makea (int z) {
    int *a1 = malloc(sizeof(int) * z);
    int i;

    srand(time(NULL));
    for (i = 0; i < tam; i++) {
        a1[i]= rand();
    }

    // remember to free a1 when you are done!
    return a1;
}
```

Also note that using malloc can **sometimes** basically grant you the 'random number' scenario for free, negating the need to loop through the elements as the value returned from malloc is garbage (and thus random numbers).

However, also note that malloc is *implementation-specific*, meaning that an implementation could theoretically clear the memory for you before returning it.

Comment: Malloc doesn't necessarily return a pointer to garbage.  On some systems, unallocated heap memory is set to a specific value on startup to aid debugging.  Depending on the reason for populating the array with random data, it may be wholly necessary to do so.

Comment: @ChrisBrowne correct, I had updated my post before you commented, obviously it hadn't updated server-side.

Comment: `srand` is used to seed the generator and does not return a value.  I realize that you are just using the OP's code, but just to be correct...

Comment: Uninitialized memory usually has the same value on each execution of a program, so it is not very random at all. The OS zeroes out memory pages that it gives to the program, so any non-zero data in the memory came from the program itself.

Comment: As far as I know, it's even worse - reading from allocated memory before writing to it is undefined behavior (and may crash your program)

Comment: @asaelr hmm never heard of that actually happening, but if it's UB anything could happen I suppose.

Comment: this work! now.. my job is generate bidimensional arrays
Thanks to all, especially @RichardJ.RossIII :D

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is:

1. Declare the array outside of the routine, and pass it in to initialize it:

   `void init_array (int a[], nelms)`
2. Plan B is pass a pointer to a pointer, and have the routine allocate and initialize it

Like this:

```
void alloc_and_init_array (int **a_pp, int nelms)
{
  *a_pp = malloc (sizeof (int) * nelms);
  ...
```

... or, equivalently ...

```
int *
alloc_and_init_array (int nelms)
{
  int *a_p = malloc (sizeof (int) * nelms);
  ...
  return a_p;
```

Comment: @patz (2) solves the question as posed, but seriously look to see if (1) works for you. With (2), use the return value to flag successful creation of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first off your function says that it returns an int, yet you want to return an array, so that is wrong.  Of course, you can't return an array in C either...

Second, you will have to return a pointer.  You cannot copy arrays via assignment or assign a new value to an array at all in C, so your function won't be very useful.  Either return an `int*` or take an `int**` as an output argument and initialize it in your function.

Also, your array is locally allocated, so even if the compiler didn't complain you would be returning invalid memory.

```
int makea (int size, int **out_array) {
    int *temp, i;
    if(!out_array)
        return 0;
    temp = malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
    if(!temp)
        return 0;

    srand(time(0));
    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i) 
        temp[i] = rand();        

    *out_array = temp;
    return 1;
 }

int main() {
    int *arr;
    if(!makea(10, &arr)) {
        printf("Failed to allocate array");
        return -1;   
    }

    return 0
}
```

Another note:

```
temp[i] = srand(time(0));
```

That is wrong.  `srand` seeds the random number generator, but does not return a random number.  You call `srand` to input the seed and then call `rand` to get a random number.

Answer (score 0):

A local variable like your array is allocated on the stack. At function return it is removed from the stack, so the pointer you return points to an unallocated memory location.

You have to allocate the array with malloc() or pass an already existing array to the function.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <time.h>    

int makea (int z) {
    int *a1 = (int*)malloc(z*sizeof(int));
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < tam; i++) {
        a1[i]=srand(time(0));
    }

    return a1;
}
```

IMPORTANT: remember to free memory allocated somewhere outside, when you do not need it anymore.